# Need to understand this sed expression

Tags: linux, sed

i was reading this questions [How to use conditional expression to select data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284960/awk-or-sed-how-to-use-conditional-expression-to-select-data)

The sed solution given was

`sed -r '1d;/(\S+\s+){5}\S+/!d;/\+$/s/\S+\s+//5;/-$/s/\S+\s+//4' file`

I could not understand the bits

`1d;` - what does this statmenet do

`/(\S+\s+){5}\S+/` - it matches any non whitespace chnacter 5 times and one more

`!d` dont know what this does

`/\+$/` this means anything that ends with +

`s/\S+\s+//5;` dont know

`/-$/`  it searches for anything that ends with -

`s/\S+\s+//4'` dont know

Comment: Have you read the `sed` man page?  All the commands are documented there.

Comment: i know the meaning of commands there but don't know what they are doing in this context. like d deletes the pattern space but don't know how it helps here with `1d`

Comment: @user55711 I've edited the original answer and added an explanation.

Comment: @potong i could not add comment there , i get everything , but could not get , how can we delete the field numbers i.e \5 , \4 . can you give me some tutorial links where they mention deleting individual fields. i did knew if thats possible

Comment: @user55711 for all things `sed` see [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

`1d;`

This simply deletes line one.

`/(\S+\s+){5}\S+/!d;`

This matches any (non whitespace character [`\S`] one or more times [+] followed by any whitespace character [`\s`] one or more times[`+`]) 5 times [`{5}`] which is then followed by a non-whitespace character [`\S`] one or more times [`+`] AND DELETES THE ENTIRE LINE FOR ANY LINE NOT CONTAINING THE MATCH [`!d`].

The syntax `/pattern/d` will search for your pattern and delete any lines containing that pattern.  Changing that to `/pattern/!d` does the opposite, in that it deletes any lines not containing that match.

`/\+$/s/\S+\s+//5;`

This searches for the pattern `\+$`, which matches any line ending in a literal plus sign.  Then it performs the action `s/\S+\s+//5` on those lines.  What this command does is to search for the pattern `\S+\s+` (which you should be able to interpret based on the explanation of the last statement), and deletes the fifth occurrence of the match on each line (not the whole line, mind you, just the matching bit).

The basic syntax at work here is `s/pattern/replacement/`.  Because the replacement was left blank, it has the effect of deleting the match.  Changing the syntax to `s/pattern/replacement/n` only replaces the nth occurrence.

`/-$/s/\S+\s+//4;`

This is almost identical to the above, except that it is searching for lines ending with a minus sign, then on those lines, deleting the fourth occurrence of the pattern.

HTH.